# HTML5 template tag code organization

Tags: html, templatetag

Is is best to inject all the template tags inside the head ?

I think this way the code will be much cleaner, which splits elements between items that can be rendered and others that not.
What do you think or what do you use yourself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is based on personal preference and the context of the templates. The `template` tag can certainly be placed with in the `head` element, as the [W3 standard allows metadata content there](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element), and the `template` element [can indeed be metadata](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#metadata-content-0). However, [the W3 code example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element) (reproduced below) shows it placed near where it is intended to be used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Cat data</title>
<script>
 // Data is hard-coded here, but could come from the server
 var data = [
   { name: 'Pillar', color: 'Ticked Tabby', sex: 'Female (neutered)', legs: 3 },
   { name: 'Hedral', color: 'Tuxedo', sex: 'Male (neutered)', legs: 4 },
 ];
</script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name <th>Color <th>Sex <th>Legs
 <tbody>
  <template id="row">
   <tr><td><td><td><td>
  </template>
</table>
<script>
 var template = document.querySelector('#row');
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
   var cat = data[i];
   var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
   var cells = clone.querySelectorAll('td');
   cells[0].textContent = cat.name;
   cells[1].textContent = cat.color;
   cells[2].textContent = cat.sex;
   cells[3].textContent = cat.legs;
   template.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: That's good if you use the template in a table or something, but if you need it for dynamic content like dialogs, modals, etc; you will find it useful to have the templates stored somewhere central.
Do you agree ?

Comment: @DamjanDimitrioski: Yes, as I said, it depends on the situation, and placing your templates in the `head` is certainly valid and may be appropriate for those situations.